Media Skip back/forward via USB keyboard keys
I have an Android 14 phone (Samsung Galaxy A15). I want to control media playback with a USB keyboard connected to my phone. The keyboard does not have dedicated "media playback" buttons.
Is there an app (or setting) that lets me do that?
I tried the app Button Mapper (by flar2) and it works for play/pause, but not for skipping back/forward.
Note that the media app I want to control is this one:
Music Player & MP3 Player by InShot Inc.
